# Rotate around the touched position using oculus controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I want to rotate an object attached (kinda grabbed, manually updating the position) to oculus controller but shouldn't be a child of the controller.

process is as follows, 
1. Lets say i have an object(Pivot (X, Y, Z)) and i touch it (A, B, C) to grab it, i am updating its position manually instead of making it child of the contoller.
2. Now the object moves along with the controller, want to calculate its rotation so that it looks like object is attached and updating its rotation based on the controller.

Any Ideas??

Comment: `but shouldn't be a child of the controller` why not? The simpliest solution in my opinion would be to temporarly make it a child of the controller and when you let it go again make it not be a child of the controller anymore.

Comment: Transform.RotateAround seems to be a good suggestion

Comment: @zambari you would need it 3 times so for every axis I guess ^^

Comment: @zambari i tried Rotatearound, each line for each axis, but facing a bug, if i rapidly shake the controller , object is rotating around the controller on the attached point.

Comment: it makes a difference between Update, LateUpdate and FixedUpdate (I think there is one more point where you can attach your code)

Answer (score 0):

Spontaneously I see basically 3 options if you don't want to make it simply a child:

#### 1. Use a [FixedJoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html)

> restricts an object’s movement to be dependent upon another object. This is somewhat similar to Parenting but is implemented through physics rather than Transform hierarchy. The best scenarios for using them are when you have objects that you want to easily break apart from each other, or connect two object’s movement without parenting.

So whenever you grab the object do something like

```
var fixedJoint = grabbedObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
fixedJoint.connectedBody = controllerObject.GetComponent<RigidBody>();

//disable autoconfigure anchor
fixedJoint.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;

// And set offsets depending on the current relative positions

// Get the position of the object in the controllers local coordinates
fixedJoint.connectedAnchor = controllerObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(grabbedObject.transform.position);

// And get the controllers position relative to the object
fixedJoint.anchor = gtabbedObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(controller.transform.posotion);
```

And wherever you release the object remove that joint e.g.

```
Destroy(grabbedObject.GetComponent<FixedJoint>());
```

#### 2. Calculate transforms

Getting the relative position offset you could also use a kind of faked parenting by simply component wise add the offset using the controllers local coordinate system.

Have a component something like that on the grabable objects

```
public class CopyTransforms : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform target;
    private Transform startOffset;

    private RigidBody rb;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
    }

    // Call this In the moment you grab the object 
    public void Grab(Transform grabber)
    {
        target = grabber;
        offset = transform.position - target.position;
    }

    // Call this when releasing
    public void Release()
    {
        target = null;
    }

    // If dealing with rigidbodies you should use fixedupdate
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(!target) return;

        // Apply rotation
        rb.MoveRotation(target.rotation);

        var targetPosition = target.position + target.right * offset.x + target.up * offset.y + target.forward * target.z;
        rb.MovePosition(targetPosition);
    }
}
```

#### 3. Use fake parenting

The idea is to have an empty object under the controller.

The moment you grab you set the position of this empty object to where your grabbed object is -> In the future whenever the controller is moved this empty object will be where your grabbed object should be. So you just have to apply it's transforms and done

```
var emptyObject = new GameObject("empty");
emptyObject.transform.SetParent(controllerObject.trasform, false);

emptyObject.transform.rotation = grabbedObject.transform.rotation;
emptyObject.transform.position = grabbedObject.transform.position;
```

Now you have to simply copy its transforms either e.g. in

```
void Update()
{
    grabbedObject.transform.rotation = emptyObject.transform.rotation;

    grabbedObject.transform.position = emptyObject.transform.position;
}
```

or in `FixedUpdate` like before.

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear.*